# Setting Hash Key value based on if-else condition in a cleaner way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for cleaner way to write this

```
{
  if(condition)
    a: 25
  elseif
    a: 32
  end

  if(condition)
    b: 25
  elseif
    b: 32
  end

}
```

I have various keys in a hash like this which are all based on the same condition.

Query 1:  Is there a better/cleaner ruby way if the condition is same for all keys?

Query 2: Is there a better/cleaner ruby way if the condition is different for all keys?

I tried writing method which accepts the condition,object1,object2 as arguments and returns object1 if the condition is true otherwise object2. It is not working.

```
def conditional(condition,object1,object2)
if(condition)
  object1
elsif
  object2
end
```

end

Comment: Try this {a: (condition ? 25 : 32 )}

Comment: Thanks , but then Rubocop is upset with line length. :-)

Comment: Actual values are as follows:

condition ? "HTTP:#{port}/}",    "HTTP:#{port}# {health_check_information[:path]}"

Comment: then try this `b =  (condition ? 25 : 32 )` then `{a:b}`

Comment: @SahilRally Can you please provide **all** important information, such as the values of `a` and `b`, in the question? It's quite important in order for us to give an answer!!

Comment: For example, in this case you could maybe do: `"HTTP:#{port}# " + condition ? " #{health_check_information[:path]}" : ''`

Comment: Problem is the length of the line becomes too big. But yes definitely it is smarter.

Answer (score 3):

If condition is the same, then you construct entire hashes in the if.

```
if condition
  { a: 1, b: 2 }
else
  { a: 3, b: 4 }
end
```

If conditions are specific, I would try extracting the logic in small specialized methods.

```
{ a: value_for_a, b: value_for_b }
```

Comment: But is that not duplicate code , not following DRY principle , I am actually using this in my code.

Comment: The second will not duplicate code (where by code you mean "hash structure"?)

Comment: I mean to say, if requirement's change and we have a different value of a key, then I need to change it at 2 places.

Comment: @SahilRally: not sure what you mean exactly, but your proposed (invalid) snippet is even more vulnerable to this.

Comment: @SahilRally _"not following DRY principle "_ – because you have to repeat the keys? You could remove that duplication, but separating the keys from their respective values probably makes your code harder to understand.

Comment: @Stefan : Yes keys are repeated and hence not DRY.

Comment: @Sergio : I am actually using what you suggested but since I thought I am repeating same hash (keys) , which does not support DRY, tried better cleaner way but it turns out to be more unclear

Comment: @SahilRally you _could_ write `[:a, :b].zip(condition ? [1, 2] : [3, 4]).to_h` instead.

Comment: @Sergio Do we have trade-off between "clean readable code" vs "DRY" .

Comment: @SahilRally There is definitely a tradeoff there. We try for both, but IMO until you start hitting real scaling problems, you should favor clean readable code so it is easier for colleagues to dive into the code.

Comment: @stefan That seems nice ! Let me investigate more on zip.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to keep getting stuff done instead of focussing way too much on what rubocop wants. I can agree that extra lengthy lines do not look nice and they should be avoided WHENEVER POSSIBLE - but sometimes it can happen that strings (for configurations of URLs etc) can get a bit lengthy, so just deactivate the line length check for this blocks, and activate it again afterwards.

```
# rubocop:disable LineLength
{ a: "blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla" }
# rubocop:enable LineLength
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) will help?

It's an expression that works like:

```
{ if_this_is_a_true_value ? then_the_result_is_this : else_it_is_this }
```

Comment: You are right, but then the problem is line becomes too big and not readable.  Actual values used are lengthy and not simple 25, 32 . For instance, "HTTP:#{port}/}"   and   "HTTP:#{port}# {health_check_information[:path]}"

Comment: @SahilRally You can always define variables before condition

Answer (score 0):

A little more readable with tap and ternary

```
hsh = Hash.new

hsh.tap do |hsh_instance|
  hsh_instance[:a] = get_value_a
  hsh_instance[:b] = get_value_b
end

def get_value_a
   condition_true? ? value_1_a : value_2_a
end

def get_value_b
   condition_true? ? value_1_b : value_2_b
end
```

Comment: rubocop will likely complain even more :)

Comment: ohh yeah, it will :)

Comment: I am kinda liking this. But issue is we have too many if else conditions in get methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try a ternary expression

a = condition ? 25 : 32

Comment: This has been suggested (in better form) at least twice now. Your answer doesn't add anything new, it seems.

Comment: When I came to this question there were no answers.